# Can't open any .cshtml file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. These are the only steps I have taken to reach this error.

1. I create a new .NET Core 2.0/2.1 Web Application (both versions result in error)\
2. I choose Web Application (Model-View-Controller)
3. After I create the project, I try to open any of the `.cshtml` files present in the generated project template, but I get one of these two errors :

   > ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjMSd.png))
   >   The given key was not present in the dictionary

   OR

   > ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCw7L.png))
   >   Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Razor..."

This happens any time I try to open any `.cshtml` file in the project. I get the first error when I have the razor extension installed and enabled, and I get the second error when I turn off the razor extension (but razor is now integrated into VS 15.3 according to visual studio and so I shouldn't need it either way).

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have tried

1. Clearing cache in `%LocalAppData%`
2. Running NuGet reinstall
3. Updating to .Net Core 2.1
4. Disabling extensions (I only had one downloaded besides the pre-packaged extensions)
5. Reinstalling VS

I'm sure it's just something I don't have downloaded or something I have overlooked, but I am really at a loss right now so would appreciate anyone who has any ideas I can try!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had disabled the **Razor Language Service Pack** a while back and had forgot to re-enable it, you can find this under Tools > Extensions and Updates

Answer (score 1):

No need to uninstall. A similar thing happened to me the other day. Whats most likely going on is your .csproj file is out of sync.

Right click on your project called Library

go to where it says edit->Library.csproj
(name of your project with the globe)

click on that. Its gonna take you to a file with xml.

take a look at your Target framework::
 if it says

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2</TargetFramework>
```

-> your on aspnetcore 2.0.x something

if you see a 2.1 or over then you have to resolve those dependencies by targeting packages that are compatible.

here is an example of my csproj file (Target framework = 2.0) 
after I messed it up grabbing 2.1.x of sqlite.

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-MyPoject-xxxxx-xxxCommented-0ut</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.Designer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

The cli-tool and the PackageReference have to be in sync with the target framwork.

I also see that you have the consent cookie so you might be running a newer version.

In that case may need to use the dotnet cli command line interface to run the project .Change that green play button from IIS Express to the name of your project in the drop down. open up the actual folder of the project via powershell..run these commands un the directory of your webapp

`dotnet restore` and then `dotnet run`

Comment: It was the right hint: In my case, I upated VS 2017 to the latest version and created an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, but forgot to update the installed 2.0 SDK to 2.1. After installing .NET Core 2.1 everything works fine :)

Comment: Happy you fixed it.

Comment: if you are wonder how to check your .Net core version then run this path in command prompt
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App